# Label filtering to get id from url

Tags: javascript, html, filter, label

The scenario is that i want a script that will fetch a custom part of a label and add it in an url. Something like this:

```
 Label: www.wbsite1.com/something.php?id=1337
```

then i want to make the script take: `id=1337` and add it to a link like this:`www.wbsite2.com/id/(car1337).html`

Im a complete beguinner in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/QATT6/1/) solve your problem?

You can read the label text and extract only the required portion of the string and then construct the required URL as:

**HTML:**

```
<label>www.wbsite1.com/something.php?id=1337</label><br>
<button onclick='navigate();'>Go</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function navigate() {
    var str = document.getElementsByTagName('label')[0].firstChild.data
    str = str.substring(str.indexOf("id=")+3, str.length);
    window.location.href = "http://www.wbsite2.com/id/car"+str+".html";
}
```

Comment: Very good example but a little hard to understand :/ 
Also it looks very good written!

Answer (score 0):

use lastIndexOf() find '?' from the end , the function will return the index of the '?' in the url string, and then you can use substring() to get the substring after the '?' the index.

so, here you get the substring, then find id ande value and you now you can use '+' to concatenate several strings .

```
<script language="javascript">
var url = "www.wbsite1.com/something.php?id=1337";
var index = url.lastIndexOf( "?" ); //get the position of the '?' 
var str = url.substring( index+1 ); //get the string after url;
var _idx = str.indexOf( "=" ); //get the '=' position.
var id = str.substring( 0, _idx);
var value = str.substring( _idx );
var final_string = "www.wbsite2.com/"+id+"/(car"+value+").html";
alert( final_string );
</script>
```

Comment: Great example! easy to understand :) Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
//str is your Label value

var str_sub = str.substr(str.lastIndexOf("=")+1);
```

Then concatenate the grabbed id (1337) to other string you want to manipulate.

Comment: Nice basic example :) Thanks